# How to write in new line in file in Python

Tags: python, file, optimization, split, newline

I have a file that is like this:

```
word, number
word, number
[...]
```

and I want to take/keep just the words, again one word in new line

```
word
word
[...]
```

My code so far

```
f = open("new_file.txt", "w")
with open("initial_file.txt" , "r+") as l:
for line in l:
    word = line.split(", ")[0]
    f.write(word)
    print word # debugging purposes
```

gives me all the words in one line in the new file

```
wordwordwordword[...]
```

Which is the pythonic and most optimized way to do this?
I tried to use `f.write("\n".join(word))` but what I got was

```
wordw
ordw
[...]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use `f.write(str(word)+"\n")` to do this. Here `str` is used to make sure we can add "\n".

If you're on Windows, it's better to use `"\r\n"` instead.

Comment: sometimes I wonder whether it's better to call `write()` twice - with the text to be printed and the newline in order to avoid unnecessary string concatenation, e.g. `f.write(str(word)); f.write(os.linesep)`

Comment: And I don't know whether there was `os.linesep` back in 2015, but I guess in order to keep your code clean, future proof and platform independent you should use it instead of `\n` or `\r\n`