# save Python list to a txt file in nice order

Tags: python

My project is a shopping-list "app" where you can basically just add stuff, and later check what you added.

now I want to save this list to a txt file.
i know how to do that sort of...

But my output in that txt file looks like this "bananaketchuphamburgerspizza"
what I want is of course for all of this items to write

```
banana
ketchup
hamburgers
pizza
```

something like that. more readable in short.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write in new line in file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183347/how-to-write-in-new-line-in-file-in-python). If not, please show your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Shopping lists typically have quantities, as well, by the way. Are you getting one bottle of ketchup, or a packet of ketchup, for example

Comment: use file.write(word+"\r\n")

Comment: `file.write('\n'.join(your_shopping_list))`